# Escape special character # in table condition clause

Tags: java, android, escaping, special-characters, android-sqlite

Creating the table in SQLite with column names which contains special character `#`.

Don't know how to escape this so that SQLite recognize it.

I found that the escape code for `#` is `%23`. So I tried to do like this:

```
condition = condition.replace("usernum#", "usernum%23");
```

where condition is the SQLite condition of type string, for example, `select * from users where id = '2' ORDER BY usernum#`

But the above way is giving SQLite Exception.

**LOG:**

```
04-12 20:00:44.395: E/AndroidRuntime(8054): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: usernum (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Users WHERE id !=1 order by Type DESC, usernum%23 ASC
```

**Error is in this line:**

```
Cursor curr = db.rawQuery("select " + fields + " from " + table + " "+ condition, null);
```

Comment: which exception are you getting?

Comment: i assume you are using a rawQuery ? (is usernum# a column ? seriously ?)

Comment: oh yes I am using rawquery. See my update.

Comment: you probably can quote it (with double quotes)

Comment: for one, don't use rawQueries.

Comment: My condition is coming dynamically and its already a string in double qoutes, so how to quote the specific `usernum#` part in double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 04-12 20:00:44.395: E/AndroidRuntime(8054):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: usernum (code
>   1): , while compiling: select * from Users WHERE id !=1 order by Type
>   DESC, usernum%23 ASC

Since column contains special character, solution is to wrap it to double quotes(whole column) and it will work

```
select * from test order by "username#" desc;
```

In your case:

```
String query = "Select * from users where id = ? ORDER BY \"usernum#\"";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Solution with query() method:

```
String[] columns = {...};
String selection = idColumn + " = ?";
String[] args = {String.valueOf(id)};
String orderBy = "\"" + orderByColumn + "\"";
Cursor c = db.query(table, columns, selection, args, null, null, orderBy);
```

Comment: Can't I do that in replace method itself? My condition is containing large ORDER BY sequence which is also dynamic and its not just `usernum#` and also this whole rawquery code is in method which is taking dynamic parameters as `public Cursor getData(String fields, String table, String condition) {// rawquery code}`

Comment: @SaurabhJain each column that contains special character need to be wrapped in double quotes how i mentioned.

Comment: ok that's fine but how to get the `id` field like you wrote `String.valueOf(id)`. My this field is coming in string form and its inside the `condition` string of getData method. Do I need to take it from there as a substring?

Comment: @SaurabhJain it was only pseudo-code for imagination. since your id is string you don't need to cast it again to String so simply insert to args only id.

Comment: Ok, now my query ran without exception this time but now double quotes is coming around `usernum#`. I just did like: `condition = condition.replace("usernum#","\"usernum#\"");` and the condition query became: `WHERE id !=1 order by Type DESC,ASC,"usernum#",Name DESC`. Any idea how to remove double qoutes within condition string i.e. `"usernum#"`?

Comment: @SaurabhJain why remove???? usernum column have to be wrapped in double quotes or query wont work. what is confusing??

Comment: The problem is the query `select * from users where id !=1 order by Type DESC,"usernum#" ASC,Name DESC` is not giving correct result. It should be: `select * from users where id !=1 order by Type DESC,usernum# ASC,Name DESC`. See the difference between the two.

Comment: @SaurabhJain i wrote twice times! your usernum# have special character, it must be wrapped in "usernum#". query gives you wrong results problem will be elsewhere. i tested it myself and all works correctly.